# The current date parameter not adding to file in jcl

Tags: mainframe, zos, dfsort

```
 //STEP001  EXEC PGM=SORT                           
 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                             
 //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                             
 //SORTIN   DD DSN=XXX.T.KR0A9N99.XXXIFRDK.PARM,    
 //            DISP=SHR                             
 //SORTOUT  DD DSN=XXX.T.KR0A9N99.XXXIFRDK.PAR1,    
 //            DISP=SHR                             
 //SYSIN    DD DSN=XXX.T.KR0A9N99.TWT.PARM(XXX@DATE)
 //            DISP=SHR
```

Inside this file XXX.T.KR0A9N99.XXXIFRDK.PARM

```
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+
***************************** Top of Data ***********************
open xxxF01Q@SDTPRD.fbabank.com                                  
CD SDT_WINDSS/Download/                                          
LSITE trailing_blanks=yes                                        
SPUT //'xxx.T.KR0A9N99.xxxDHOLA.CSVF.SR0096(0)' HOLD.20190524.CSV
QUIT
```

inside parm XXX.T.KR0A9N99.TWT.PARM(XXX@DATE)

```
OPTION COPY                                                
INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,4,CH,EQ,C'SPUT'),OVERLAY=(54:&DATE1))
```

the job went successful but not updated the  current date for this file HOLD.20190524.CSV.. could you please help me to get correct date?

Comment: 1 - not a JCL question but a DFSORT question (and MAINFRAME)
2 - You showed the input to your sort and your sort control statements but not the output
3 - you did not show your DFSORT messages so we cannot see if you missed a message.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a SYSIN RECFM issue. It sounds as if your SORTOUT file equals your SORTIN file. If so, that means the condition is never true. One explanation could be that, because of the RECFM, the argument SPUT might not be in position 1 the way it appears to be in the ispf screen shot. For example, if the RECFM of the SYSIN file happens to be FBA then, although the value appears to be in column 1, it would really be in column 2. If the input file is VBA or VB then the value would be offset by either 2 or 4.

It would be interesting to know the RECFM of the SORTIN file.